# DataTables - Calling functions in 'columnDefs' in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables

So when I'm creating a DataTable in react, defining a certain column using the [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property.

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
              "targets": 7,
              "data": "data",
              "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return "<button onclick='test()'>view</button>"
              }
            }
          ]
```

But as expected, it can't find the `test()` function. Is there anyway to do this jsx style or something? Or will I just have to create the function inside the onclick?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
$('#your_table').DataTable({

. . . 

"columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 7,
                "data": "data",
                "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return "<button class='view_btn' data-id='"+data+"'>view</button>"
                          }
              }]
```

Then create the test function outside:

```
$('#your_table').on('click', '.view_btn', function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  test(id); // your function
});
```

Comment: I'm more or less looking for a way to do it the react way, e.g. `onclick={this.test}`. If it's not possible, then a 'not possible' answer with an explanation would do it. This is one way to get around it though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use render in this case as the function will be called directly. You can use arrow function and [createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) insetead in `columnDefs`.
For example you have a function in a component:

```
 this.test= this.test.bind(this);
```

Call that function in `columnDefs` by:

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "targets": 0,
  "data": "data",
  "createdCell": (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => {
    $(td).click(e => {
      this.test();
    })
  }
}]
```

Take a look at the link above for more information.

Comment: you're probably right, though I don't have access to the code anymore so I can't really mark it as an answer :(

Comment: Old answer, but it works. easily customizable. ty

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arrow function and `this` object

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
              "targets": 7,
              "data": "data",
              "render": ( data, type, full, meta ) => {
                return "<button onclick='this.test()'>view</button>"
              }
            }
          ]
```